# Cumulocity Regionalization

Tags: cumulocity

Is it possible to adapt data display in Cumulocity to the current location of the accessor. E.g. to adapt date, time and units to the location and timezone of the current viewer.

This is necessary for machines that are distributed worldwide but data in cumulocity is viewed remote of the machine location. Therefore data need to adapt to preferred unit at that location as well as current timezone.

Does anybody have a solution approach or best practice to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cumulocity UI uses moment.js so all timestamps are displayed in the local time of the browser.

For storage every timestamp is stored with the timezone that it was send with and will be returned as such on the REST API.